# How can I set a thumbnail image for posts where user did not set one

Tags: wordpress

I want the theme to set a thumbnail image for a post if the user did not choose a thumbnail for when they created the post.

I tried looking through the WordPress codex but I could find any "set method".

```
<div class="standard-featured">
    <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <img src="//Set your image default Path here.">
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. Here is a cleaner way to do it. The code example below.

```
<?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>

  <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>

<?php else : ?>

  // Dafult thumbnail image for post. try to write the exact image location.
  <img src="default.jpg" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the function `set_post_thumbnail()`.

More information can be found here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_post_thumbnail/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set post thumbnail from post detail page (single.php). Then first of all add image from wordpress media. Copy it's post id from admin panel or database.

Call below function.

```
 $post_media_id= '';/ id of your uploaded image
 $current_post_id = get_the_ID();// current post id            
 set_post_thumbnail($current_post_id , $post_media_id);
```